# How do i pass keyUp/keyDown events to panel in visual basic?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, events

I have created a game in visual basic, and have decided to expand by adding multiple rooms on the game. Each room will be a panel that shows when the user enters a certain area. To start, I created a class that inherits panel properties, then added it to my main Form. I then added all the items to the panel controls. My issue is that i cannot control the player when it is in the panel controls. I have tried all sorts, but couldn't get it to work.

I did some reading and found that panel does not come with keyUp() and keyDown() events. However, I would like to know if there is a way round this.

Thanks in advance!

Code of mainRoom() class (my panel):

```
Public Class mainRoom
    Inherits Panel

    Sub New()
        With Me
            .SetBounds(0, 0, Form1.Width, Form1.Height)
            .SendToBack()
        End With
    End Sub

    Public Sub mainRoom_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.DarkOrange, block)
    End Sub
End Class
```

In main form class:

```
Sub setMap()
    main = New mainRoom()
    Me.Controls.Add(main)
End Sub
```

Comment: You said it inherits Panel but it looks like it inherits PictureBox, no?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I was experimenting with some stuff. I have changed this now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `KeyPreview=True` on the main form, and then handle the key up/down events from the form:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.KeyPreview = True
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    'key down code.
    e.Handled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyUp
    'key up code.
    e.Handled = True
End Sub
```

Note: if you don't want other controls' key up/down event handlers to fire after your form event handlers do, then set `e.Handled=True` as I have in the above example.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more info on KeyPreview.

Comment: I have tried this and no success. I want the panel to handle key presses as that is where my player is being drawn to, not the form.

Answer (score 0):

BEWARE - when moving (cut/paste) existing controls via the IDE from a form into a new panel control, the event handlers are not carried across as they become children of the parent control (the new panel). So this happens:

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
```

Add the event handlers back and don't spend an age googling why keypress events suddenly stop firing in panels ...

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
```